# Expecting a class body when trying to create an instance of Fotoapparat

Tags: android, kotlin

OK so I'm trying to use the Fotoapparat library [(link)](https://github.com/RedApparat/Fotoapparat) and honestly I'm getting slightly confused but trying to work it out.

This is the basic initialization according to the documentation:

```
val fotoapparat = Fotoapparat(
    context = this,
    view = cameraView
)
```

Now `view` is expecting an item of type `CameraRenderer`.

I think the right approach (not sure though tbh) is as follows:

```
val cameraView = object : CameraRenderer

    val fotoapparat = Fotoapparat(
        context = this.context,
        view = cameraView
    )
```

but now I have an error on the `val fotoapparat` variable saying `expecting a class body`

I'm pretty lost and not sure how to start using this library.

*Any recommendations for a different simple and effective camera library with documentations for kotlin are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the sample code the cameraview is id of xml view:

```
  <io.fotoapparat.view.CameraView
        android:id="@+id/cameraView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:visibility="visible">
```

so add above into your xml and remove this below line:

```
     val cameraView = object : CameraRenderer
```

reference: [activity_main](https://github.com/RedApparat/Fotoapparat/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) and here is kotiln code [cameraView](https://github.com/RedApparat/Fotoapparat/blob/72c7c81a420545d0f9645e4b5bba1d69d08a3caf/sample/src/main/java/io/fotoapparat/sample/MainActivity.kt#L45)